# How to get the values of marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, dictionary, android-maps-v2

Hi there a novice in apps creation would like to know is there any way to get the info of a selected marker to another activity.?

Have read few articles that get around the point but not the one that gives a clear idea of the scenario.
Any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly your use case?

Comment: have a activity where the google map is displayed with markers.Want to get the details of the marker to another activity having a text-View widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `InfoWindowAdapter` to your map which has `getInfoWindow` handler with `Marker` parameter. Sample:

```
GoogleMap map;
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        //marker is selected marker
        View popup = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.somePopupXml, null);
        //code to fill popup with data
        return popup;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The marker is a final class, you can't derive with your class, so you have got two options: use an hashmap with the pair your objects-marker object, pick the right object when there is an onClik on the marker and send the id to the second activity or use your id in the info window. In second case when the marker is clicked you can re-parse the info window, get the id and send it to the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will answer your question as I am using maps in android for the first time too, but you can assign a clicked marker's title ETC to variables once it has been clicked.

```
'@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        title = marker.getTitle();              
        current=marker.getPosition();

    return true;
    }'
```

If you need more than one marker you can do an if statement and have the position for example save to a new variable then increment it.